# Which will be best approach for doing Unit Test for SLIM framework having REST API calls in PHP

Tags: php, rest, unit-testing, phpunit

I have implemented the Integration Testing for REST API calls using SLIM Framework. Now i need to implement the Unit Test for REST API calls so that i can do Test Driven Development for my API development.

There will be multiple calls so there will dependency injection as well.

Below is the code i have as of now:

```
protected $client;

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    }


    public function testGetClass() {
        $organizationId = "15";
        $data = array();
        $response = $this->client->post(BASE_URL . API_PATH . 'getclass', [
            'json' => [
                'class_id' => '10.128',
            ]
        ]);
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        if (isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
            $data = $data['data'];
            $resp_id = (isset($data['organizationId']) && $data['organizationId'] != "") ? $data['organizationId'] : "";
            $this->assertEquals($organizationId, $resp_id);
        }
    }
```

This work well.... It will be very helpful if someone can point me in right direction to create Unit Test environment with some helpful links or articles.

Currently i am going through below link but i would love to get more information which i may not cover or miss.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Any help/assist is appreciated.

Comment: What you are talking about is not unit test, it's functional/acceptance test. Look at [codeception](http://codeception.com/). It's a very cool tool for functional/acceptance testing, I strongly recommend it

Comment: @NikitaU. what i have achieved so far is integration testing now i need to know how to perform unit testing which is more inclined to test driven development.